# htmx: e.querySelectorAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, htmx

If I use [hx-swap-oob](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/), then I get an error:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.3.3/dist/htmx.js"></script>
<div id="sum">?</div>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><button 
   hx-get="https://run.mocky.io/v3/b5a6902e-fc46-479b-92e4-9b4befc7a920"
   hx-target="closest tr">1</button>
  </td>
  <td>one</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

After pressing "Run Code Snippet" and then press `1`:

```
htmx:swapError
{
  "message": "e.querySelectorAll is not a function",
  "filename": undefined,
  "lineno": undefined,
  "colno": undefined
}
```

The [mocky http endpoint](https://run.mocky.io/v3/b5a6902e-fc46-479b-92e4-9b4befc7a920) returns this:

```
<tr>
  <td>2</td><td>two</td>
 </tr>

<div id="sum" hx-swap-oob="true">MAGIC</div>
```

In above example I use the non minified version, so the error message is: `eltOrSelector.querySelectorAll is not a function`

If I use this endpoint, it does not fail: https://run.mocky.io/v3/2ab904eb-23a9-4006-b68b-f112b55841f3

But in my usecase the new html fragment should be `<tr>...</tr>`, not a `<div>`.....

JS stacktrace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: eltOrSelector.querySelectorAll is not a function
    at findAll (htmx.js:295)
    at handleOutOfBandSwaps (htmx.js:501)
    at selectAndSwap (htmx.js:712)
    at doSwap (htmx.js:2284)
    at handleAjaxResponse (htmx.js:2358)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (htmx.js:2163)
```

## Update

I could narrow down the issue to this:

[image: devtools]

This fails:

```
makeFragment('<tr><td>a</td></tr> <div>X</div>')
```

## Update2

hmmm, now I know why it fails:

[image: makeFragment]

`parseFromString()` of Chrome is the root-cause:

[image: parseFromString]

## Update3

Follow-up question: [Make parseFromString() parse without validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67313479/make-parsefromstring-parse-without-validation)

## Update4

I created an issue, hoping someone with more creativity has an idea how to solve this: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/469

Comment: I only discover htmx with this question, so I am really not sure about it, but for your response to have the tr>td part parsed correctly, it would need at least a `<table>` element around. And indeed, using [this end-point](https://run.mocky.io/v3/39b3dd91-9129-4308-a76e-4b7fc82b7e44) it writes "MAGIC".

Comment: @Kaiido yes, you are right the result looks good with your endpoint. But if you inspect the HTML with devtools, then there is the <table> from the response inside the <tr>. That's not valid. But you idea brought me an idea which I will try next ...

Answer (score 1):

As per your issue, HTMX team has created a config that can be enabled to support table fragments like this. Documented example here: https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/#oob. As noted,  it is not IE11 compatible.

```
htmx.config.useTemplateFragments = true;
```

Execute the following in a js file after htmx has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [new endpoint](https://run.mocky.io/v3/28a8e653-491c-4186-abd4-4f48f3579273) which returns a slightly different HTML fragment:

```
<table>
 <tr id="row1">
  <td>2</td><td>two</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div id="sum" hx-swap-oob="true">MAGIC</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.3.3/dist/htmx.js"></script>
<div id="sum">?</div>
before table
<table>
 <tr id="row1">
  <td><button 
   hx-get="https://run.mocky.io/v3/28a8e653-491c-4186-abd4-4f48f3579273"
   hx-target="#row1" hx-select="#row1">1</button>
  </td>
  <td>one</td>
 </tr>
</table>
after table
```

HTMX uses [parseFromString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) internally, and this method validates the input. If there is non valid HTML, it might truncate elements.

`makeFragment()` of HTMX wraps the string which it sends to `parseFromString()`. HTMX looks at the first element in the response. In above question it is `<tr>`. Thus htmx uses `<table>` to wrap the whole http response.

[image: makeFragment()]

The solution is the return a "normal" element to htmx (not `<tr>`).

Normal html fragments in htmx are exactly one element, so that it does not matter. If you use `hx-swap-oob` the server sends several elements to the client.

This is more or less a work-around. It would be great if htmx would handle the original string.